# communication between 2 rest web services

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have many rest controllers in my project (developed with spring MVC) and i would like to make them communicate between each other.
what's the best way to make two spring  REST controllers exchange messages  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposed you have 2 controllers:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/first")
public class FirstController(){
// your code here
}
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/second")
public class SecondController(){
    // supposed this is your FirstController url.
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/yourapp/first";
    // create request.
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    // execute your request.
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
   // do whatever with the response.
}
```

For reference, have a look at this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Used library: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Comment: Thank you @Tuan  this way is very useful. But can you  tell me how did 2 controller exchange messages without modifying their codes. I need something like orchestration or middlewares ?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot think about a better idea... :( I think you can use the SecondController to call the FirstController to get what you want.